# How to plot the world without the countries’ boundaries?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the world map and I found this interesting Package. But this plots also the countries’ boundaries.

```
         require(maptools)
         data(wrld_simpl)
         plot(wrld_simpl)
```

Is there a way to get rid of the countries’ boundaries?

Comment: I thought I could do it with `library(rgeos); gUnaryUnion(wrld_simpl)` but a few "rogue" countries refuse to get merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the borders are poorly aligned in that data set. Often a small buffer can fix this.

```
require(rgeos)
wbuf = gBuffer(wrld_simpl,width=0.00001)
plot(wbuf)
```

but beware that your coastlines are now buffered by 0.00001 degrees...

Sometimes a buffer of size zero does the trick, but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

overplotting:

plot of world, filling the countries with a tan color and making the country boundaries the same color:

```
map('world', col = 'navajowhite3', fill = T, border = 'navajowhite3',
    bg = 'lightcyan3',
    ylim = c(-90, 90))
```

make a transparent plot of just the coastlines:

```
map('world', interior = F, add = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will create  a map in gray color without national boundaries. Use add = TRUE only to  add the map to the current plot, otherwise set add = FALSE:

```
map('world',interior=FALSE,add=TRUE,col='gray', fill=TRUE,lty=0)
map('world',interior=TRUE,add=TRUE,col='gray')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `maps` package.

#### Example

```
require(maps)
map("world", col=1, fill=TRUE, border=1)
```

[image]